# Android using sharedpreferences in BaseAdapter class

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

In activity I load preferences like:

```
   public void LoadFontSize(){
        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        loadedFontSize = sharedPreferences.getString("fontsize", "font3");
      }
```

And SharedPreferences sharedPreferences; is declared globally.

I have an ExpandBaseAdapter class operating an ExpandableListView. I want to handle fontsizes in this class, but it shows me

> The method getApplicationContext() is undefined for the type
>   ExpandBaseAdapter

error.

I tried to add  `sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("PREF_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`
but then I get only the default value.

If I add    `sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ExpandBaseAdapter.this);`
I get

> The method getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context) in the type
>   PreferenceManager is not applicable for the arguments
>   (ExpandBaseAdapter)

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the application context when you create the instance of this base adapter in your activity.

and declare context as attribute in the base adapter constructer.

Comment: No, Declare your base adapter in your activity like this, BaseAdapter = new BaseAdapter(getApplicationContext()); then in your base adapter use global variable Context mContext; then inside the constructor of the base adapter use mContext = context; then use mContext inside your function.

Comment: Can't happen mate, this is the only way you can pass the context, try to work around, maybe you are missing something.

Comment: By the way, did you ever set another value to that sharedprefernces so you don't get the default value??

Comment: It occured to me later that I didn't do exactly what you had told me. I kept that adapter class in a separate java file. Then I put it inside the activity and it works! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to use YourActivity.this instead of getApplicationContext(), both in general, and especially in your Adapter.

Best regards.

(Edit below)

Try this then:

```
class ExpandBaseAdapter {
  Context mContext;
  void ExpandBaseAdapter(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
  }
}
```

and use mContext.getSharedPreferences() where you need it.

Comment: This is not an activity. Like I said, this is class ExpandBaseAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter

Answer (score 0):

Pass a Context object into `LoadFontSize()` as a parameter and use that to get to shared prefs.

Comment: You mean LoadFontSize(context); and public void LoadFontSize(Context zContext){ sharedPreferences = zContext.getSharedPreferences("PREF_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); loadedFontSize = sharedPreferences.getString("fontsize", "font1"); } ?? still getting the default value